# Python print two unique strings from list

Tags: python

I am trying to print two unique strings from the movies list one in day one and one in day two. So far I have tried random.choice but then I switched to random.shuffle. I have two movies showing but they are both showing on both days and I'm not sure what step to take to separate the two.

```
from flask import Flask
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True      # displays runtime errors in the browser, too

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # choose a movie by invoking our new function
    movie = get_random_movie()

    # build the response string
    day1 = "<h1>Movie of the Day</h1>"
    day1 += "<ul>"
    day1 += "<li>" + movie + "</li>"
    day1 += "</ul>"

    # build the response string
    day2 = "<h1>Movie of the Day Tomorrow</h1>"
    day2 += "<ul>"
    day2 += "<li>" + movie + "</li>"
    day2 += "</ul>"

    return day1 + day2

def get_random_movie():
    movies = ["Akira", "Ghost In The Shell", "Princess Mononoke", "Kimi no na wa", "Howl's Moving Castle" ]
    random.shuffle(movies)
    return movies[1] + movies[2]



app.run()
```

Here is my output

Movie of the Day
Howl's Moving CastleAkira


Movie of the Day Tomorrow
Howl's Moving CastleAkira

Comment: How exactly is [tag:flask] related to the specific question you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are connecting two strings, what you want is return a tuple from your function and then assign the values properly

```
from flask import Flask
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True      # displays runtime errors in the browser, too

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # choose a movie by invoking our new function
    movie = get_random_movie()

    # build the response string
    day1 = "<h1>Movie of the Day</h1>"
    day1 += "<ul>"
    day1 += "<li>" + movie[0] + "</li>"
    day1 += "</ul>"

    # build the response string
    day2 = "<h1>Movie of the Day Tomorrow</h1>"
    day2 += "<ul>"
    day2 += "<li>" + movie[1] + "</li>"
    day2 += "</ul>"

    return day1 + day2

def get_random_movie():
    movies = ["Akira", "Ghost In The Shell", "Princess Mononoke", "Kimi no na wa", "Howl's Moving Castle" ]
    random.shuffle(movies)
    return (movies[1], movies[2])



app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. Reading up on tuples now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: you were returning movie[1] + movie[2], the python understands it as one variable string... but if you want to return two separate values you have to use tuple, list or array...

Answer (score 0):

You can either encapsulate the values as lists or use list slicing:

```
[movies[1]] + [movies[2]]
```

Or:

```
movies[1:3]
```